# Audio CD won't mount but DVD does

Tags: mount, dvd

I have an annoying issue.

If I put a DVD in the drive and run sudo blkid it seems to have been detected no problems. This is the output from blked

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="aaf5e7ea-0a55-4d6a-9c44-9ec6322780cb" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="Bfpm3T-FhUH-SXdP-PC7V-UGPP-4UrG-nzJwdN" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="storage" UUID="45dc816e-5208-4698-a861-9b521dc2fb1c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="tv_shows" UUID="b0a5a614-bcb8-4c29-9e52-e13258aaa5de" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/lancelot--vg-root: UUID="82da3fa2-7865-483e-b8c5-8d940a524643" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/lancelot--vg-swap_1: UUID="d21d735e-c759-4aee-9c53-0c792c843c45" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="CHARLIE_AND_LOLA" TYPE="udf"
```

If I put in an Audio CD though, I get nothing. It's like the CD isn't even in the drive. This is the output from blkid

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="aaf5e7ea-0a55-4d6a-9c44-9ec6322780cb" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="Bfpm3T-FhUH-SXdP-PC7V-UGPP-4UrG-nzJwdN" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="storage" UUID="45dc816e-5208-4698-a861-9b521dc2fb1c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="tv_shows" UUID="b0a5a614-bcb8-4c29-9e52-e13258aaa5de" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/lancelot--vg-root: UUID="82da3fa2-7865-483e-b8c5-8d940a524643" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/lancelot--vg-swap_1: UUID="d21d735e-c759-4aee-9c53-0c792c843c45" TYPE="swap"
```

Anyone have any ideas on whats going on?

Comment: Your drive may be breaking down or the lens for cd's is dirty. `sudo blkid` is not useful for audio cd's as they have no filesystem & consequently aren't really 'mounted', just accessed at a location, cdda://sr0/ ; cdda://sr1/ ; cdda://sr2/ ect.

Comment: @doug: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 0):

Copied answer from comments:

Your drive may be breaking down or the lens for cd's is dirty. `sudo blkid` is not useful for audio cd's as they have no filesystem & consequently aren't really 'mounted', just accessed at a location, `cdda://sr0/`; `cdda://sr1/`; `cdda://sr2/` etc...